# I'm having a hard time getting date/time components from day of year and seconds since midnight

Tags: c++, date, time, epoch

In my data stream, I have seconds since midnight and days since January 1st...I will be manually specifying a year, so I need to be able to convert those three values to a correct date/time to output to another program.  Here's my code:

```
int currentDay = XPLMGetDatai(gLocalDate); // days since Jan 1st
float currentTime = XPLMGetDataf(gZuluTime); // seconds since midnight
int currentYear = 2015;

struct tm t;
struct tm * ct;
time_t t_of_day;

t.tm_year = currentYear - 1900;
t.tm_yday = currentDay;
t.tm_hour = (int)(currentTime / 3600);
t.tm_min = (int)(currentTime - (t.tm_hour * 3600)) / 60;
t.tm_sec = (int)currentTime - ((t.tm_hour * 3600) + (t.tm_min * 60));

t_of_day = mktime(&t); // should convert t into a valid time_t
ct = gmtime(&t_of_day); // should give me a valid UTC from t

// Send data to Celestial Control
CCelC.SetDay(ct->tm_mday);
CCelC.SetHour(ct->tm_hour);
CCelC.SetMinute(ct->tm_min);
CCelC.SetMonth(ct->tm_mon);
CCelC.SetYear(currentYear);
```

The problem I seem to be having is the fact that currentDay being plugged into tm_yday is getting obliterated when the mktime(&t) gets called. So I end up with a ct->tm_mon of 0, which is incorrect in my test run of currentday 90 (April 1).

So given any year, any seconds since midnight, and any days since jan 1, how can I generate correct day(1-31), hour(0-23), min(0-59), mon(1-12), year values?

Comment: Why not use `<chrono>`?

Comment: And do you want `Jan 1` of the current year or [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Comment: I don't believe `<chrono>` knows anything about dates, leap years, months, days in a month, etc. I would recommend taking a look at Boost's `datetime` library.

Comment: @erip I need the actual day of the month (1-31) and the actual month (1-12) of the given year and given number of days since Jan 1.

Comment: @Steve I'd really like to avoid using any external libraries if possible.  I feel like I'm pretty close with what I have above, but I'm missing something for the conversion.

Comment: @RobbieP. That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: You can't use `mktime` to do this. From [these docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) "The values of the members tm_wday and tm_yday of timeptr are ignored ..... A call to this function automatically adjusts the values of the members of timeptr if they are off-range or -in the case of tm_wday and tm_yday- if they have values that do not match the date described by the other members."

Comment: @erip I think I must have misunderstood your question then.  I'm using days since Jan 1 of the given year in my code as a source. I don't need epoch time...I need the individual date/time elements.

Comment: @SimonGibbons that explains why it's getting dumped then...Is there a way to convert a yday into a month and day of the month for a given calendar year?

Comment: There is a way - I'm writing it up now as an answer.

Comment: @SimonGibbons At this point, I'm thinking I need to convert my values into seconds since epoch...And go from there, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `mktime` to do this in the way you want to. From [these docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/)

> The values of the members tm_wday and tm_yday of timeptr are ignored
>
> .....
>
> A call to this function automatically adjusts the values of the members of `timeptr` if they are off-range or -in the case of `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`- if they have values that do not match the date described by the other members."

However you can take advantage of this behavior to populate the other fields correctly. If you instead set up the fields of the `struct tm` like so

```
struct tm t = {0};

t.tm_mday = currentDay + 1;
t.tm_year = currentYear - 1900;

t.tm_sec = currentTime;

mktime(&t);
```

This method works because of the automatically adjusting behavior of `mktime`

As a fully working example

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int currentDay = 90;
    int currentTime = (12*3600 + 52*60 + 31);
    int currentYear = 2015;

    struct tm t = {0};

    t.tm_mday = currentDay + 1;
    t.tm_year = currentYear - 1900;

    t.tm_sec = currentTime;

    // mktime will now correctly populate
    // tm_sec, tm_min, tm_hour
    // tm_day, tm_mon, tm_year
    mktime(&t);

    // Print the time to make sure!
    std::cout << asctime(&t);
}
```

Will output

```
Wed Apr  1 12:52:31 2015
```

Comment: Only problem here is that currentDay is days since January first...not day of the month.  So this won't work I believe. So like in a non-leap year, currentday 90 would be April 1st.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up, in which case you can then just set `mday` to be `currentDay + 1`

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example program showing it working.

Comment: Missing needed `tm_isdst` in `main()`.  Better to start with `struct tm t = {0}` as other fields may be present that need initialization  "The tm structure shall contain at _least_ the following members ..."

Comment: @chux Thanks for the spot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument for using `<chrono>`.  This argument is not without its downsides.  However I believe that in the long run, migrating towards this system will have benefits in type safety (correctness), performance and readability.

The downsides include the need for an 3rd party open source free header-only (one single header) library (for now):

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h

This will also require C++11 or forward (naturally because it builds on `<chrono>`).

I will present this solution in stages:

1. The first stage uses `<chrono>` only for the conversion, and gains little in terms of type-safety.  The input and output at this stage is integral.
2. The second stage starts showing benefits when the input stage adopts `<chrono>` types for its own interface.
3. The third stage shows significant benefits when both input and output have adopted to `<chrono>`.

**Infrastructure**

Assume a `struct CCelC` like so:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct CCelC
{
    int year_;
    unsigned month_;
    unsigned day_;
    int hour_;
    int min_;
    int sec_;

    friend
    std::ostream&
    operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CCelC& x)
    {
        using namespace std;
        auto f = os.fill();
        os.fill('0');
        os << setw(4) << x.year_ << '-'
           << setw(2) << x.month_ << '-'
           << setw(2) << x.day_  << ' '
           << setw(2) << x.hour_ << ':'
           << setw(2) << x.min_ << ':'
           << setw(2) << x.sec_;
        os.fill(f);
        return os;
    }
};
```

And a test driver like this:

```
int
main()
{
    auto t = convert(90, 12*3600 + 52*60 + 31, 2015);
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}
```

**Stage 1**

The first stage builds a `CCelC convert(int currentDay, float s, int y)` conversion function that takes scalar inputs and output a `CCelC` which itself takes scalar inputs.  The only use of `<chrono>` here is to input scalars, do the date computation, and output scalars:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>

CCelC
convert(int currentDay, float s, int y)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tp = sys_days{year{y}/jan/1} + days{currentDay} + seconds{static_cast<int>(s)};
    auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
    auto time = make_time(tp - dp);
    auto ymd = year_month_day{dp};
    return {int{ymd.year()}, unsigned{ymd.month()}, unsigned{ymd.day()},
            int(time.hours().count()), int(time.minutes().count()),
            int(time.seconds().count())};
}
```

This auxiliary [(free, open-source one-header) library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h) is needed to make the date computations convenient.  It simply converts the input year/day/second field types into a `std::chrono::time_point` and then converts the `std::chrono::time_point` back out into year/month/day hour:minute:second scalars.

This solution is roughly equivalent to the currently accepted (and good) answer.  Both solutions do not require calendrical arithmetic on the part of the user.  This driver for this solution outputs:

```
2015-04-01 12:52:31
```

**Stage 2**

Imagine that the input code for `convert` decides to convert to `<chrono>`.  This has significant type safety advantages.  The compiler can now help you correctly convert units and protect you from confusing `minutes` with other integral types which have nothing to do with time units.  This will effectively turn potential run-time errors into compile-time errors (catching your errors at compile-time is always better).

The `convert` function is now specified to take chrono types:

```
CCelC
convert(date::days currentDay, std::chrono::duration<float> s, date::year y)
```

`date::days` is just a type-alias for `24 std::chrono::hours`.  `date::year` is a new type, but helps disambiguate `2015` from some arbitrary integer. Now `2015_y` has type `year` and the compiler propagates that information for you.

Our driver can now become much more readable (assuming C++14 for chrono duration literals):

```
int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto t = convert(days{90}, 12h + 52min + 31s, 2015_y);
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}
```

There is a slight simplification in the implementation of `convert` with this new API:

```
CCelC
convert(date::days currentDay, std::chrono::duration<float> s, date::year y)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tp = sys_days{y/jan/1} + currentDay + duration_cast<seconds>(s);
    auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
    auto time = make_time(tp - dp);
    auto ymd = year_month_day{dp};
    return {int{ymd.year()}, unsigned{ymd.month()}, unsigned{ymd.day()},
            int(time.hours().count()), int(time.minutes().count()),
            int(time.seconds().count())};
}
```

There is no longer a need to convert the scalar input into the type-safe units of the `<chrono>` library.  Much of the work of `convert` remains in adopting to the scalar format needs of `CCelC`.

**Stage 3**

But what if `CCelC` adopted `<chrono>`?  Logically, if it did so, it should store a `std::chrono::time_point` instead of all of those fields.  It is more space efficient, and it is easy (using [date.h](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)) to convert to field types when necessary.  This might look like:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct CCelC
{
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
                                               std::chrono::seconds>;
    time_point tp_;

    friend
    std::ostream&
    operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CCelC& x)
    {
        using namespace date;
        return os << x.tp_;
    }
};
```

The functionality *hasn't changed at all here.*  The output of this program is still `2015-04-01 12:52:31`.  And the sizeof requirements have just *dramatically* dropped.  And the performance for arithmetic involving seconds, minutes, hours and days has just sky-rocketed.

The `convert` function has also just gained performance and simplification.  Its input hasn't changed at all, so the driver is still the same.  But now `convert` does not need to convert back to scalar types:

```
CCelC
convert(date::days currentDay, std::chrono::duration<float> s, date::year y)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return {sys_days{y/jan/1} + currentDay + duration_cast<seconds>(s)};
}
```

The code now has been so significantly simplified that the chance for logic errors is greatly reduced.  This simplification includes type-safety so that the compiler helps you catch logic errors. There are no more units conversions exposed in code, eliminating another class of errors.  And if you wrap timers around this code, you will find it runs **fast**:

[Cppcon 2015 video presentation of date.h](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo)

Maybe `<chrono>` isn't something you can completely adopt today.  But there are advantages to adopting it in small stages, in small parts of your code.  [date.h](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) can help.  And down the road in 2 or 3 years, `<chrono>` is what you want to be aiming for.  Eventually this is what the C++ community will be adopting universally.  `<ctime>/<time.h>` is dead.  The type-safety and performance advantages of `<chrono>` are too great.  This answer is a description of how you can get on board with `<chrono>` gradually, one small piece of code at a time.